# Generating a list of alternative packages with apt tools

Tags: apt

Given a package how can I list all possible packages that are alternatives to this package? 
In the alternate, how can I tell if a package or one of it's alternates is installed?

Using something in the apt family of tools, of course.

Comment: you mean alternatives, as in /etc/altrnatives, or just functionally similar

Comment: Did you check if my answer is correct?

Answer (score 2):

For example, if you want to list all the alternatives to `nano` run:

```
apt-cache showpkg nano
```

to determine that it provides the `editor` virtual package.

Then run:

```
aptitude search "?provides(editor)" | grep -v ":"
```

to list all alternatives

```
p   deutex                          - composition tool for doom-style WAD files 
p   edbrowse                        - /bin/ed-alike webbrowser written in C     
p   emacs24                         - GNU Emacs editor (with GTK+ GUI support)  
p   emacs24-lucid                   - GNU Emacs editor (with Lucid GUI support) 
p   emacs24-nox                     - GNU Emacs editor (without GUI support)     
p   fte-console                     - Text editor for programmers - console edit
p   fte-terminal                    - Text editor for programmers - version for 
p   fte-xwindow                     - Text editor for programmers - X Window Sys 
p   jed                             - editor for programmers (textmode version) 
p   jove                            - Jonathan's Own Version of Emacs - a compac
p   jupp                            - user friendly full screen text editor     
p   le                              - Text editor with block and binary operatio
p   ledit                           - line editor for interactive programs      
p   levee                           - very small vi clone                       
p   mg                              - microscopic GNU Emacs-style editor        
i   nano                            - small, friendly text editor inspired by Pi
p   nano-tiny                       - small, friendly text editor inspired by Pi
p   ne                              - easy-to-use and powerful text editor      
p   pluma                           - official text editor of the MATE desktop e
p   rlfe                            - Front-end using readline to "cook" input l
p   rlwrap                          - readline feature command line wrapper     
p   scite                           - Lightweight GTK-based Programming Editor  
p   vigor                           - nvi with the evil paperclip               
p   vile                            - VI Like Emacs - vi work-alike             
i   vim                             - Vi IMproved - enhanced vi editor            
p   vim-athena                      - Vi IMproved - enhanced vi editor - with At
p   vim-gnome                       - Vi IMproved - enhanced vi editor - with GN
p   vim-gtk                         - Vi IMproved - enhanced vi editor - with GT
i   vim-nox                         - Vi IMproved - enhanced vi editor - with sc 
i   vim-tiny                        - Vi IMproved - enhanced vi editor - compact
p   xjed                            - editor for programmers (x11 version)      
p   xul-ext-password-editor         - edit password manager entries in Mozilla a
p   xvile                           - VI Like Emacs - vi work-alike (X11)
```

`grep -v ":"` is here to filter architecture specific packages.

Also beware because some packages provides multiple virtual packages by example `openbox` provides `x-window-manager` and `x-session-manager`. So if you want to replace a given package, the replacement package has to provide all the virtual packages of the original one.